# Improper use of foldM with IO [Bool] for arg parsing

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell, I'm trying to map a check function that checks if a file exists and looks like this:

`check :: FilePath -> IO Bool`

To the argv from Main, like so:

```
main :: IO Bool
main = do {
    args <- getArgs;
    return $ foldM (&&) True $ mapM check args;
}
```

Basically the logic is, fold the array of IO [Bool] into a single IO Bool and return it. I'm using the Monadic versions of Map and Fold, since I'm carrying the IO monad around, but I'm getting a lot of errors from the typechecker, which I can't really decipher since placeholders are introduced that I know nothing about.

```
src/Main.hs:15:9: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘m0 Bool’ with ‘Bool’
      Expected type: IO Bool
        Actual type: IO (m0 Bool)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        return $ foldM (&&) True $ mapM check args
      In the expression:
        do args <- getArgs
           return $ foldM (&&) True $ mapM check args
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do args <- getArgs
                 return $ foldM (&&) True $ mapM check args
   |
15 |         return $ foldM (&&) True $ mapM check args;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src/Main.hs:15:24: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Bool’ with ‘m0 Bool’
      Expected type: Bool -> Bool -> m0 Bool
        Actual type: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
    • In the first argument of ‘foldM’, namely ‘(&&)’
      In the expression: foldM (&&) True
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘foldM (&&) True $ mapM check args’
   |
15 |         return $ foldM (&&) True $ mapM check args;
   |                        ^^^^

src/Main.hs:15:36: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Bool]’ with ‘Bool’
      Expected type: IO Bool
        Actual type: IO [Bool]
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘mapM check args’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘foldM (&&) True $ mapM check args’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        return $ foldM (&&) True $ mapM check args
   |
15 |         return $ foldM (&&) True $ mapM check args;
   |
```

Any clues how to make the typechecker happy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `foldM` is:

```
GHCi> :t foldM
foldM
  :: (Monad m, Foldable t) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
```

The binary function you give it should produce a monadic result in some monad `m` (in your case, `m` would be `IO`). `(&&)`, however, doesn't produce a monadic result. That means you don't need `foldM` here: a plain fold will do:

```
GHCi> :t foldr (&&) True
foldr (&&) True :: Foldable t => t Bool -> Bool
```

Incidentally, `foldr (&&) True` is available in the Prelude as `and`, so you can just use that instead. To apply `and` to your `[Bool]` list in `IO`, you can use `fmap`. The final line of your do-block then becomes:

```
fmap and $ mapM check args
```

Or, using `(<$>)`, which is the infix spelling of `fmap`:

```
and <$> mapM check args
```

(As Sebastian Redl points out, the `return` is unnecessary, as `and <$> mapM check args` is of type `IO Bool` already.)

---

By the way, note that giving `main` the type `IO Bool` won't do what you expect -- the return value of `main` is discarded. To return an error exit code, you can use, for instance, [`exitFailure`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/System-Exit.html):

```
argsOK <- and <$> mapM check args
if not argsOK
    then exitFailure
    else return ()
-- rest of your do-block
```

(`return ()` is merely a do-nothing placeholder here.)

A nicer way of expressing that is using `when` from `Control.Monad`:

```
argsOK <- and <$> mapM check args
when (not argsOK) exitFailure
-- rest of your do-block
```

Comment: Awesome answer, clears out a lot of things about fmap and Monads thank you! One small detail is, that even if my `main` returns `False` the return value of the called process is always 0. Is there anyway to make it return some error codes like -1 in the case of unsuccessful execution of my command line tool? I've seen System.exit but I'm looking something that matches the C int main behavior.

Comment: @rausted To set the return code, you have to explicitly call a termination function, as those in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/System-Exit.html

Comment: @rausted I added an extra section addressing that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the only error, but the result of your `foldM` call is already `IO Bool`; no need to `return` it. That only wraps it in another layer of monad.